# Need to convert Decode Strings that come from a DB

Tags: python-2.7, utf-8, cgi, decode

Good Day,

I have a problem that below code, gives me the following results.

'HEllo there'] ['Unterl\xc3\xa4nderstr. 46'] ['Weilimdorf B\xc3\xbcrohaus'] ['Property Name'] ['Hello on the other side'] ['Jahnstra\xc3\x9fe'] ['Bahnhofstr. 15'] ['Karlsruher Str. 3'] ['Bahnhofstra\xc3\x9fe 69'] ['Florians Haus'] ['Property Number 22'] ['Schickardstr.36'] ['Clichystr. 6'] ['Property Name 2'] ['Kirchstra\xc3\x9fe 5'] None

I need the \xc3\xa4 to be shown as the UTF-8 letters that they correspond too but cant get it to run. I hope someone here had a similar problem.

```
import cgi
import cgitb
cgitb.enable()
import sqlanydb

def db_dropdown():
  con = sqlanydb.connect( userid="DB", pwd="123", eng='DB',dbn='DB' )
  cursor = con.cursor()
  sql ="select distinct [Property] from Asset_Zielfonds"
  cursor.execute(sql)
  rowset = cursor.fetchall()
  encoded = [[s.encode('utf8') for s in t] for t in rowset]
  return encoded


def print_dropdown(data):  # Print the dropdown
    print '<div>'
    #print '<select>'
    for i in data:
        print '%s' % (i)
    #print '</select>'
    print '</div>'

print "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n"
print '<html>'
print '<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">'
print '<head>'
print '</head>'
print '<body>'
print '<h2>Retrieval of Data from DB</h2>'
print '<br>'
print '<br>'
print '<br>'
print print_dropdown(db_dropdown())
print '<br>'
print '<br>'
print '<br>'
print '</body>'
print '</html>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by using following code.

```
def db_dropdown():  # Execute query
    db = sqlanydb.connect( userid="", pwd="", eng='',dbn='' )  # Your DB details here
    cursor = db.cursor()

    sql ="select distinct [Property] from assets where  [Property] is not NULL"

    cursor.execute(sql)
    list_tested = cursor.fetchall()  # Get query response and store in variable
    list_tested = [i for sub in list_tested for i in sub]  # Convert to list from tuple
    return list_tested



def print_dropdown(data):  # Print the dropdown
    print '<div>'
    print '<select>'
    for i in data:
      print '<option value="%s"selected>%s</option>' % (i.encode ('utf-8'), i.encode ('utf-8'))
    print '</select>'
    print '</div>'
```